# How do you switch fragments in viewpager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager that has 3 Fragments:

```
    VP = new SettingsScrollViewPager( this );
    VP.setScrollDurationFactor( 4 );
    VP.setId( "ST".hashCode() );
    setContentView( VP );

    // add fragments
    ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentsContainer = appHelper.addFragments( 
        new SettingsFragment(),
        new SearchFragment(),
        new FavoritesFragment()
    );

    VP.setAdapter( new SettingsFPA( getSupportFragmentManager(), fragmentsContainer ) );
    VP.setOffscreenPageLimit( 1 );
    VP.setCurrentItem( 0 );
```

I want to replace FavoritesFragment with SearchFragment after a button is clicked, but how do I do that? It should look like this:

```
    ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentsContainer = appHelper.addFragments( 
        new SettingsFragment(),
        new FavoritesFragment(),
        new SearchFragment()
    );
```

This is how my adapter looks like:

```
public class SettingsFPA extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private static ArrayList<Fragment> mFragments;

public SettingsFPA( FragmentManager manager, ArrayList<Fragment> container ) { 
    super(manager);
    mFragments = container;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragments.size();
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragments.get(position);
}
```

}

I should swap Index 1 with Index 2, that's all I want to achieve, so any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Can't you replace the `PagerAdapter` with a new one that has the desired ordering?

Comment: Yes, but I really don't want to do that and it doesn't work as I want to see. Why isn't there no method for replacing or adding fragments? This is quite annoying.

Comment: You can just change index in fragment array list and call notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this works:

Create method inside SettingsFPA class

```
public void swapFragments() {
    Collections.swap(mFragments, 1, 2);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

From activity call swapFragments on button click:

```
mSettinfsFPAAdapter.swapFragments();
```